# Postfix double exclamation mark in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I know the double negation prefix, and I know TypeScript's single postfix (non-null assertion).

But what is this double postfix exclamation mark?

`/.*verification code is (\d{6}).*/.exec(email.body!!)!![1]`

Taken from [here](https://github.com/mailslurp/examples/blob/master/javascript-cypress-mailslurp-plugin/cypress/integration/integration-test.spec.ts).

Answer (score 12):

It's similar to how `!!` works in JavaScript, except pointless.

`!` asserts that the previous expression is non-nullish.

`!` can be used after expressions.

`expression!` asserts that `expression` is non-nullish.

`expression!!` asserts that `expression!` is non-nullish.

A single `!` suffices, but more are not syntactically prohibited. The following is valid too:

```
/.*verification code is (\d{6}).*/.exec(email.body!!!!!!)!!!![1]
```